# AspNetCore adding new database relation to AspNetUser

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working in visual studio 2017, i created a web with this properties:

**asp.net**

**mvc**

**individual User Account**

But i changed the model of AspNetUser:

In Models:

```
ApplicationUser (add)
    {
        ...
        [ForeignKey]
        [InverseProperty("ApplicationUser")]
        public virtual UserProfile UserProfile {get; set;}
    }

UserProfile
    {
        ...
        [InverseProperty("UserProfile")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser {get; set;}
        [ForeignKey]
        [InverseProperty("UserProfile")]
        public virtual UserImage {get; set;} 
    }

UserImage
    {
        ...
        [InverseProperty("UserImage")]
        public virtual UserProfile {get; set;}    
    }
```

Later  i do a migration in nuget console, when in my view save my user with their profile, this work fine (i did a check in my db), but, when i try to get the user's profile is null.

I used this code.
In my controller AccountController for my view UpdateUser i put this

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

public AccountController(..., UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) {
    this._userManager = userManager;
     ....
}

public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser() {
    ApplicationUser currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    ...
}
```

Now, when my controller in the function UpdateUser do action `await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User)`, this load not open the related table UserProfile because of that the field UserProfile in  *currentUser* is null. In asp.net 5 i can load this profile using `HttpContext.GetOwinContext<applicationDbContext>()` but aspnetcore don't has this

How i can do that (or What do I have to change so that the function  `GetUserAsync(User)` load the user and their profile automatically)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core does not support lazy-loading. As a result, navigation properties like your `UserProfile` will be null unless you either eagerly or explicitly load them. Eager loading is achieved by utilizing `Include` with your query. However, `UserManager` affords you no opportunity for that. As a result, you would need to do an explicit load after getting the user:

```
var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
await context.Entry(currentUser).Reference(x => x.UserProfile).LoadAsync();
```

Alternatively, you can actually pull the user from your context. You don't have to use `UserManager`. It just makes some things easier.

```
var currentUser = await context.Users.Include(x => x.UserProfile).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

However, it should be noted that `UserProfile` should go away entirely. One of the whole points of Identity is to give you an extensible user object. If you need your user to have an image, add an image property directly on `ApplicationUser`. Having a separate profile object is just another join that has to be made for no reason. The only reason ASP.NET Membership had a `UserProfile` was because `User` was *not* extensible.

Comment: I used UserProfile not only for user's image, i put anothers fields in this table. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: That was just an example. All properties that apply to a "user" should be directly on `ApplicationUser`. You don't need a separate `UserProfile` entity.

Comment: ```ApplicationUser``` with  imageType, image(byte[]), imageName, birthdate and any others is very ugly for me. And in the future if AspNetUser change (normal updates that asp makes) you will not have big problems with this migration in your app. But i repeat you "Thanks a lot for your answer!!"